# Insert CKEditor HTML into Database

Tags: php, mysql, insert, ckeditor

```
Upload Error: 

UPDATE pages set page_title = 'Test Update', page_description = 'Test Update', page_content = '
This is content! Update!

\r\n' WHERE id = 

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

How can I get over this error when I submit the form to update the record?

Comment: you have no `where` clause - you realize you'd be updating ALL records in the db? And what error ARE you getting?

Comment: Can you add the error message ?

Comment: Added the error message to original question. Please note... It's a second issue! (Slightly different)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to encode the data in some way. And decode it when retrieving.